# Let $S=\{(a,b,c):a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\}$ such that $f(z)=x+ay+i(bx+cy)$ is analytic then $L(S)=$ The linear span of $S$ is isomorphic to

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S=\{(a,b,c):a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\}$ such that $f(z)=x+ay+i(bx+cy)$ is analytic then $L(S)=$ The linear span of $S$ is isomorphic to

$(a) \,\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{R})$

$(b)\, \mathbb{R}^2(\mathbb{R})$

$(c)\, \mathbb{R}(\mathbb{R})$

$(d) \,\mathbb{R}^3(\mathbb{R})$

Using $C-R$ equations, I got $a+b=0$ and $c=1$. So $S=\{(a,-a,1):a\in\mathbb{R}\}$
From this, can anybody please help.

Comment: What is meant by the notations ${\bf C}({\bf R})$ etc.?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the vector space of complex numbers over the real field.

Answer (score 1):

$(1,-1,1)$ and $(-1,1,1)$ belong to $S$. Any pint of $S$ can be written  as $(a,-a,1)=\lambda (1,-1,1)+\mu (-1,1,1)$ where $\lambda =\frac {1+a} 2$ and $\mu =\frac {1-a} 2$. Hence, the span of $S$ coincides with then span of $(1,-1,1)$ and $(-1,1,1)$ and span of $S$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{2}$.